# How to insert the content in a txt file using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the following content in a txt file

```
SERVER1 = "TCAPP"
SERVER2 = ""
SERVER3 = "APPTC"
SERVER4 = ""
```

I was trying to replace the content and insert the content using powershell. I have tried the below

```
$string = Get-Content C:\Insert\log.txt
$string[0] = $string[0] -replace ("TCAPP", "hostAPP")
$string[1] = $string[1] -replace ("", "hostAPP")
$string | Set-Content -Path C:\Insert\log.txt
```

It seems the line server2 in the txt file is not updated with hostApp

Please let me know if anything needs to add

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to replace an empty string.

The command should look like:

```
$string[1] = $string[1] -replace ("`"`"", "`"hostAPP`"")
```

where the backtick character is the escape character.

Reference :
[Escaping in PowerShell](https://www.rlmueller.net/PowerShellEscape.htm).

Or you could use as string delimiter the quote character (`'`)
like this :

```
$string[1] = $string[1] -replace ('""', '"hostAPP"')
```

Comment: You need to escape it in the replace too. So `-replace ('""', '"hostAPP"')` is another way to do it.